# Causing cpp (C preprocessor) to remove C++ comments on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have a user report (unfortunately can't verify it due to lack of appropriate machine) that the C preprocessor (`cpp`) command on Mac OS X 10.6.4 doesn't remove C++/C99 double slash `//` comments from files it processes, no matter what option it's given. This is the gcc version:

```
 i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
```

Is it possible to somehow cause it to remove such comments, as one would expect from a C++ preprocessor (this is needed because `cpp` is used as part of [another tool](http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/)).

Comment: wilx's approach should have worked; please get your user to describe *exactly* what they did, what they expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: @Zack: did you try and see it work?

Comment: @Zack: I have just tried it.  I can't make cpp discard `//` style comments either.

Comment: @JeremyP: thanks! finally a response with backing

Comment: I'll admit I was surprised My cpp was based on gcc 4.2.1 which is also mty currently installed C compiler.  `gcc -E` works fine but `cpp` couldn't be made to work with any of the -x options or `-std=c99`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a formula that works with the `cpp` command: try `cpp -xc++` (note the lack of spaces between `-x` and `c++`).

```
$ printf '/* block comment */\n// line comment\nnot a comment\n' | cpp -xc++
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "<stdin>"


not a comment
```

contrast:

```
$ printf '/* block comment */\n// line comment\nnot a comment\n' | cpp -x c++
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: c: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: c++: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: warning: '-x -x' after last input file has no effect
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
```

Now '`-x c++`' is SUPPOSED to work, and DOES work on my Linux box (with gcc 4.4, but I recall it working as long ago as gcc 2.95) so it seems that Apple broke it.

I really must reemphasize the importance of providing a complete, precise test case for questions like these.  It did not occur to me yesterday to look for Apple having introduced a bug, because I know that wilx's answer *should have* worked, and in the absence of a precise description of what the OP's user tried, it was far more likely that they had something else on their actual command line that was negating it.  If the command line and error messages I show above were provided in the original question, that would have targeted everyone's attention much more effectively.

Comment: thanks for the effort. I will ask the user to try and will report what happens (it's annoying not having the machine at hand this way :-/)

Comment: Can you confirm this works on complete files run through `cpp` (as `cpp -xc++ <filename>` and not only with the printf command

Comment: Indeed it does *not* work as `cpp -xc++ <filename>`, unless `<filename>` has a C++ extension.  This is another bug of Apple's.  I'm out of ideas, I can only suggest using `cpp -xc++ < <filename>` as a workaround.  Or `gcc -E`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding either `-x c++` or `-x c -std=c99` to the command line.

Comment: This was the first thing I suggested to the user, he tried... didn't help. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

One partial solution that appears to work is invoke `gcc -E` instead of `cpp`.

```
 -E                       Preprocess only; do not compile, assemble or link
```

This indeed strips `//` comments on Mac OS X.

However, I'm still curious why there are problems with `cpp` itself.